# Angular Web Project Not Changing Pages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a Java Maven Webproject that is using Rest.  I cannot get the project to navigate more than a single time away from the index.html.  I have attempted to use various applications of routes ([Link#1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zogrnQjHZAM), [Link#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733947/how-can-i-create-an-angularjs-spa-application-that-does-not-use-routing)) and have tried some `<div ng-include=""></div>` tricks with variables controlled from the controller.  When I get a page to load, I cannot get the page to change afterwards from triggering a route (the text of the url is the only thing to display) or changing $scope variables (the variables update, but the view does not).

I have a directory structure like the following:

```
index.html
[views]
    ->[subfolder]
        ->view1.html
        ->view2.html
```

I am pretty sure that the issue lies with the directory structure.  I have a simple form in the first view and want to switch to the second view if the data from view1 passes validation.  Both views are currently sharing a controller.

***Module definition/configuration (routing):***

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngProgress', 'restangular', '$strap.directives', 'ui.event', 'ui.numeric', 'countrySelect', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'form.validation' ]
).config(function($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("/axxyr");

    $routeProvider
            .when('/loggedIn', { template: '[views]/[subfolder]/view2.html' })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/login', template: '[views]/[subfolder]/view1.html' });
});
```

***Update:***

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l2w9VOrf7ujuqQLAVbfW?p=preview) is a Plunker that shows the  example, but in my project, the $scope variable I am using to toggle the two views changes inside the view, but not in the index.html file.

Comment: can you please share your controller code, and your module definition and configuration?

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch I've added the module definition and configuration, but the controller is quite long.  I've tested the variables and function calls and they may trigger, but they are modeled off the links I shared.